# How to retrieve form-data sent from postman in express?

Tags: node.js, express, post, postman

I successfully retrieved data in node when it was `x-www-form-urlencoded` or `raw`.

```
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.post("/api/posttest", (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    res.send("POST data received");
});
```

But when I use `form-data`, the `req.body` is empty and I didn't find my data anywhere else in `req`. Can this be retrieved with express without additional modules?

Comment: what express version are you using?

Comment: @AritraChakraborty: v4.17.1

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need the express.js middleware 'body-parser' in order to retrieve/see req.body.

Body parser used to be part of express.js but has since been removed.

Comment: I though body-parser was deprecated?

Comment: @miyagisan The Express mantainers keep putting body-parser in and out of the project. At the moment it's a middle ware I believe. It was never deprecated just outside of the core project. You always had to use it as it seems to be the case in your question.

Comment: Basically from express `v4.16.0` `express.json` is equivalent to `bodyParser.json` and so on. So you don't need body parser if you are using express after 4.16